# Why is unmarshaling into a pointer variable not possible?

Tags: pointers, go

I use a pointer variable at package level:

```
var config *configuration
```

But the attempt to unmarshal into the variable results in this error: `json: Unmarshal(nil *main.configuration)`. However unmarshaling into an pointer to the pointer variable is successful. What is the reason for this?

Comment: Because it's uninitialized, therefore `nil`, which is an invalid argument to Unmarshal as specified in the docs. But a pointer to a nil pointer is not nil itself that's why that works.

Comment: .. to illustrate: https://play.golang.org/p/y3h_dD9bePU. And the first paragraph [here](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) states that an error is returned if v is nil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is unmarshaling into a pointer variable not possible?

It is possible. In fact, it's required. Unmarshaling to a non-pointer is not possible.

> ```
> json: Unmarshal(nil *main.configuration)
> ```

This error isn't saying you can't unmarshal to a pointer, it's saying you can't unmarshal to a nil pointer. The pointer must point to a valid (probably zero-value) variable.

Replace

```
var config *configuration
```

With

```
config := new(configuration)
```

or

```
config := &configuration{}
```

and it should work just fine.